# Which version of Node.JS is better to use for production environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building an app with Node.JS and I currently use the version 4.2.4 of this framework. But I'm wondering if this version is the best for a production environment.
I have found similar question but their are old post, and NodeJS v4 and v5 doesn't exist at this time.
So which version of NodeJS is better to use for production environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question is very subjective, and any answer now is likely to change and no longer be accurate as new releases are pushed.  However, I would abide by the versioning standard provided.  V4.2.4 is LTS (Long Term Support), and is listed as being "Mature and Dependable", while v5.3.0 Stable is listed with "Latest Features" on the downloads for each version at the official nodejs.org site, at the time of this comment.

Comment: I don't see why this question is subjective. It's a fact what the "latest stable release is" All you do is look at the website. I agree the question would of been easy to lookup but  in no way subjective.

Comment: @wuno it is subjective simply for the fact that either v4 or v5 of node (at the time of this writing) could be considered "best" depending on quite a variety of factors.  The fact that both releases use similar "Dependable" vs "Stable" terminology only highlights the fact that neither version is considered beta, buggy, etc., and it's not a good candidate for a permanent answer which may be completely different versions with these labels a year from now.

Comment: Yes you could argue what is more stable. But if 4 and 5 or both labled stable its common sense which is the latest stable build. "Latest" can only be one.

Comment: @wuno but that wasn't the question asked.

Comment: ya know man your right, im sorry. Ya i think i was reading about latest stable build and i just added that to his question in my head. you guys are right i apologize.

Comment: This should not be closed, it's an important question and the versioning in node and npm is a complete nightmare, especially to new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a node application in production, you need to keep stability, performance, security, and maintainability in mind. Outlined here is what I think are the best practices for putting node.js into production.

You need to run the latest stable version of node when in production. Following this tutorial will teach you to keep your balance of stability in check. Also will help teach you how to keep up to date with the latest stable build

[Article here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/06/02/node-js-in-production/)

Please [check here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/) when you need to know the latest stable release of node.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best option is to stick to v4 which is LTS.